# $\sum_{i=0}^{S/2} (S/2+3/2)^{2i}\frac{2\cdot\Gamma(a) \Gamma(i+0.5)}{\sqrt(\pi) \Gamma(a+i+1)} {S \choose 2i} B_{\frac{S-2i}{2}}^{1+S}(0.5+S/2) $

Tags: summation, bernoulli-polynomials

Show that the following sum 
\begin{equation}
K=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{S/2}  (\frac{S}{2}+3/2)^{2i}\frac{2\cdot\Gamma(\alpha) \Gamma(i+0.5)}{\sqrt(\pi) \Gamma(\alpha + i +1)} {S \choose 2i} B_{\frac{S-2i}{2}}^{1+S}(0.5+\frac{S}{2})
\end{equation}
is positive for **any** even integer S and $\alpha>0.5, \alpha < 12$. $B_{j}^{k}$ is the generalized Bernoulli polynomial. I can only check this numerically, because this is an alternating sum, but maybe anyone has an idea how to show this  in general?

Comment: Where on earth did you get such a problem? Anyhow, note the middle of the sum should just be the Beta function; also replace $S/2$ with a different variable to simplify things.

Comment: It is related to a problem in string theory, namely positivity of the residues of the Veneziano ampltiude, see also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/99643/why-does-bosonic-string-theory-require-26-spacetime-dimensions/99667 an answer further down, where one can rephrase the residue as a sum of coefficients $K_i$, where $K_i$ are coefficients of Gegenbauer polynomials. The simplest one is $K_0$ which can be written in the form of the sum above. It is known to be positive, but no one has shown this algebraically so far afaik. I dont quite see how the given suggestions help though.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with sums involving generalized Bernoulli Polynomials, but the rest of the terms aren't too bad. We are essentially scaling a binomial expansion by values of the Beta function. Afraid I don't know any identities for sums involving generalized bernoulli polynomials off the top of my head though.